# Кнопка не передаёт информацию

Tags: laravel, button

```html
 <td>

              <form action={{ route('task.status', [$task]) }} method="POST">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
                  <button type="submit">check</button>


              </form>

          </td>
```

Это сама кнопка

```
 Route::post('/', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' =>'PostController@check_box'])->name('task.status');
```

Это роут

```
public function check_box(Task $task)
{
    dd($task->name);
        if ($task->is_active == true) {
            dd($task->is_active);

        $task->is_active = false;
        $task->save();

        }else{
            $task->is_active = true;
            $task->save();

        }


    return redirect('/');

}
```

это сам контроллер
+ у меня указана модель чтобы переменная task брлась из бд

```
 public function boot()
{
   Route::model("task",Task::class);
    parent::boot();
}
```

кнопка на dd в контроллере выдает при любом запросе информации id, name и т.д. выдаёт null подскажите что именно не верно и если есть статья по данному вопросу с радостью прочитаю , сам ничего подобного не нашёл

Comment: а в шаблоне в переменной есть значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, при написании кода соблюдай [рекомендации чистого кода](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices) (методы классов пиши в `camelCase`).

[Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding) работает при нескольких условиях:

1. Определить параметр в маршруте:

```
Route::post('/{task?}', ['middleware' => 'auth', 'uses' =>'PostController@checkBox'])->name('task.status');
```

2. В параметрах контроллера определить переменную с именем, которое соответствует имени параметра в определении маршрута

```
// /{task?} 
public function checkBox(?Task $task = null){
    dd($task)
}
```

Comment: благодарю за совет, я только учусь